# Looped cursor to match fields

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, cursor

I need to compare two lines in one table to update fields in lineB wich are filled out in lineA. My problem is, that the two fields I need to compare only partially match. So I can't just perform an update statement over a LIKE comparison.

The field I need to compare contains a generated filename. 
This name exist twice in the table one time without the word 'Bestand-' attached to the beginning one time without this. 
In order to update lineB with the information from lineA I need to match these two names.

A schematic representation of the table looks like this.

```
 Id    DateinameMarbilder        PfadNeu       
  1    Bestand-one               night      
  2    Bestand-two               evening      
  3    Bestand-three             morning        
  4    Bestand-four              noon
  5    one                       NULL
  6    two                       NULL
  7    three                     NULL
  8    four                      NULL
```

These are only the two fields I need to read, the table is much larger.

I tried to accomplish that by using a cursor and a loop.
I get a syntax Error for the forth line wich I don't seem to be abled to resolve. It seems to be a problem with the declared values. 
In addition to that am I not quite sure how to make the second cursor loop through all the lines to find a matching field an then performe the Update. Unfortunately the table is not organized so I can't just compare the next line to the one before that.

Here is the Query I tried:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE curing()

BEGIN
DECLARE tester INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE name CHAR(50);
DECLARE tempColName CHAR(50);
DECLARE tempCol CHAR(30);

DECLARE schreiber_cursor1 CURSOR FOR 
SELECT DateinameMarbilder FROM marbilder;
DECLARE schreiber_cursor2 CURSOR FOR 
SELECT DateinameMarbilder FROM marbilder;

DECLARE update_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT PfadNeu FROM marbilder;


DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
FOR NOT FOUND SET tester = TRUE;


OPEN schreiber_cursor1; 
OPEN schreiber_cursor2;
OPEN update_cursor;

get_name: LOOP
FETCH schreiber_cursor1 INTO name;
FETCH schreiber_cursor2 INTO TempColName;
FETCH update_cursor INTO tempcol; 
IF tester THEN 
    LEAVE get_name;

IF name LIKE %TempColName THEN 
UPDATE marbilder SET 'PfadNeu'=update_cursor ;  

ELSE FETCH [[NEXT] FROM] schreiber_cursor2 INTO TempColName;

CLOSE schreiber_cursor;
CLOSE update_cursor;

END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly all you need is just this. But make sure to take a copy of this table before executing this

```
Update marbilder as t1 inner join marbilder as t2 on 
t1.DateinameMarbilder  like  concat(',%',t2.DateinameMarbilder)       
set
t2.PfadNeu=t1.PfadNeu
where t1.DateinameMarbilder like '%-%' and t2.PfadNeu is null
```

Comment: It seems to work just fine. Thank you!
Just the comma before the % is a typo.